# Error en MVC 5 .NET "Could not find a factory, that creates an instance of the JavaScript engine with name `MsieJsEngine`."

Tags: .net, mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Esto me ocurre desde que añadí el `nuget` de `javascriptEngineSwitcher`. He instalado todos los `nugets` necesarios, seguidos los requisitos de ayuda, y en stackoverflow en ingles lo que dicen no solventa el problema.

Tengo 2 proyectos , uno en `VB.NET` con `MVC5` el cual funciona correctamente con los mismos `Nugets`. Mi proyecto con el problema es de `MVC 5 C#`.

¿Alguna idea de como solventarlo?

En un `layout` de `MVC 5`, tengo un `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")` que produce el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>
> Could not find a factory, that creates an instance of the JavaScript
>   engine with name `MsieJsEngine`.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
>   actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
>   acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción:
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a factory, that creates an instance of the JavaScript engine with
>   name `MsieJsEngine`.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 5:       Línea 6:      @ViewBag.Title Línea
>   7:      @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") Línea 8:
>   @Styles.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUIcss") Línea 9:
>   @Styles.Render("~/bundles/kendoCss")
>
> Archivo de origen:
>   d:\PPD\Semminer\i_dooFlow\TheflowAdminPanel\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml
>   Línea: 7
>
> Seguimiento de la pila:
>
> [JsEngineNotFoundException: Could not find a factory, that creates an
>   instance of the JavaScript engine with name `MsieJsEngine`.]
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineSwitcher.CreateEngine(String
>   name) +158
>   BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.<>c__DisplayClass1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   +24    BundleTransformer.Less.Internal.LessCompiler..ctor(Func`1 createJsEngineInstance, VirtualFileManager virtualFileManager,
>   CompilationOptions options) +27
>
>   BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1
>   assets) +226
>   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1
>   assets, Boolean isDebugMode) +95
>
>   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Transform(IList`1
>   assets, BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse,
>   VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, Boolean isDebugMode) +81
>   BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext
>   bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, Boolean isDebugMode)
>   +362    BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext
>   bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse) +35
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context,
>   String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +273
>
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext
>   context) +141
>
>   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext
>   context) +45
>
>   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String
>   virtualPath) +166
>
>   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1
>   assets) +205
>   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat,
>   String[] paths) +35
>   System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[]
>   paths) +107    System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(String[] paths)
>   +21    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\PPD\Semminer\i_dooFlow\TheflowAdminPanel\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:7
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
>   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__2(TextWriter
>   writer) +232    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter
>   writer) +10    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult
>   result) +80
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +291    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: creo que te hace falta poner el nombre del archivo `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/archivo.css")` Desconosco si esto pueda ser la solución ya que no he trabajado sobre los `_layouts.cshtml`, pero por lo regular veo que ponen el nombre del archivo

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo, resulta que en el fichero /App_Start/BundleConfig.cs había una llamada dentro de un CustomStyleBundle a un fichero Bootstrap.less que ya no existía!!! y por esto daba este error tan poco clarificador.

Ha sido quitar esa referencia en la deifnicion del CustomStyleBundle para ese estilo y ya se ejecuta correctamente sin este error.

Saludos!!!

Comment: acepta esta respuesta clickeando en el check verde del costado, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio :D